# How to do OAUth support in IMAP c-client library

Tags: c, imap

We are using IMAP c-client library in our application to download emails .
Currently We are opening  IMAP session by providing user name and password to imap_open() utility.

Now We want to implement oAuth support in our Application rather than asking the users to share their credentials details with us .

I have gone thorough the Gmail IMAP oAuth documentation and as per the documentation we can do oAuth  support by sending the  command AUTHENTICATE by the following way 
AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH (Base64 encoding of auth request parameter).

I have verified the IMAP c -client library utilities and not found any API's which does the similar thing.

Also oAuth support in PHP IMAP library has already  included.

Can any one suggest how to do oAuth support using c-client library .

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement new Authenticator to add support for OAUTH/XOAUTH2 support similar to the other authenticators we have auth_md5.c/auth_log.c,etc

Answer (score -1):

Question is old but really important. 
Don't know how you can use c-client.

But using php_sockets Implemented a simple library.
Delete mail function is not yet added. But you can take a look if it satisfies your need.

Try example. https://github.com/vmuthal/VivOAuthIMAP

Or else you can go for Zend.